# Запись информации в буфер обмена в старом API

Tags: android

Вот как можно записать информацию в буфер обмена:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.setText("Text");
```

Проблема в том, что такая возможность возможна только если API level >= 11
Какой есть альтернативный способ для API уровня ниже?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText("text to clip");
} else {
    android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("text label","text to clip");
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

Данный код работает как на старых, так и на новых версиях